# Postsharp: Method signature for Aspect

Tags: aop, postsharp

Can i specify that an OnMethodInvocationAspect can only be applied to a specific method signature, for exemple "int methodname(ClassA obj)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by overriding the method CompileTimeValidate and returning false if the MethodBase has not the expected signature.